# Is $f(x) = (x-1)\sqrt{|\ln x|}$ not differentiable at $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I tried solving the problem using the "Limits definition" of Differentiability but I can't figure out where am I going wrong. Here's my approach:
$$f(x) = (x-1)\sqrt{|\ln x|}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\sqrt{|\ln (1-h)|}}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\sqrt{|\ln (1+h)|}= \lim_{h\to 0^-}\sqrt{|\ln (1-h)|} = 0 $$
I verified using graph and finding derivative of the function that the function is indeed not differentiable at $x=1$.
Any corrections to my approach and any other method(s) to solve such a problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is absolutely uninteligible, please edit it using MathJax correctly

Comment: Wolfram Alpha delifers $f'(x) = ((x - 1) \log(x))/(2x \cdot|\log(x))|^{3/2}) + \sqrt{|\log(x)|}$ For $x>0$ as well as $x<0$ it is differentiable and the derivations have the same limes for $x\to 0$ so it's derivation is also continuous.

Comment: Sry, of course I meant the case $x>1$, $x<1$ and the limit $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $$f(x)=(x-1)\sqrt{|\ln x|},$$
we compute
$$ \begin{align}\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{|\ln x|}=0\end{align}$$
so $f$ **is** differentiable at $x=1$, and $f'(1)=0$.

---

The effects at work here are the same as with the (less obfuscate) function
$$ g(x)=x\sqrt{|x|}=\operatorname{sgn}(x)|x|^{3/2}.$$
For $x>0$, we simply have $g(x)=x^{3/2}$ and $g'(x)=\frac 32\sqrt x$. For $x<0$, we use that $g$ is odd so that $g(x)=g(-x)=\frac32\sqrt{|x|}$. For $x=0$, we find from the definig limit $g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{|x|}=0$. This can be summarized as
$$g'(x)=\frac32\sqrt{|x|} $$
so $g$ is continuously differentiable. The appearance of absolute value (as required to make $g$ even defined for $x<0$) and sign function do not hinder differentiability - in this case.

Comment: Worth noting that this limit is one-sided, as $f$ is really only defined $[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KeeferRowan You mean $(0,\infty)$? The limit is two-sided

Comment: Sorry, thought the absolute value was inside the ln for some reason....

Comment: No, because the derivative has log(x) in the denominator which makes the derivative undefined as log(x) is 0 at x=1.

Comment: @SamarthJain The OP asks about $f'(1)$ only. Are you talking about the generic expression for $f'(x)$ at $x\ne1$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Yes, I got the mistake, I was not paying attention to the fact that it does not matter that function's value at the point does not participate in deciding its differentiability. And, since $g(x)$ is odd, shouldn't that be $g'(x)= -\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|x|}$ for
$x<0$ ?

Comment: @Samarth: a functions value at a point does not matter in evaluating its derivative at that point.

Answer (score 3):

If you differentiate the function you will find that plugging in 1 will cause a division by zero. Isn't that good enough of an argument?

Comment: this proves the derivative is not continuous.

Comment: @zwim The derivative isn't even discontinuous. The function behaves like $|x|^{3/2}$ near $x=0$, so the derivative is like $\frac32|x|^{1/2}\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and continuous in spite of abs and sgn

Comment: I did not examinate the derivative in fact I was merely answering that plugging a value in the derivative is not the same as differentiability in one point.

Answer (score 0):

It is insufficient to realize that the formula for the derivative involves dividing by $0$ at a point to conclude that that the function is undifferentiable at that point. The calculation shown earlier in this exchange shows that by the definition of derivative, it is differentiable at $x=1$ and there $f'(1)=0$.

Another clue would be to take the limit of the formula for the derivative as $x \to 1$, where you would find that ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1} f'(x) = 0}$. So it is continuously differentiable every where it is defined, $(0, \infty)$.  Taking that derivative involves L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Sorry: I meant taking that limit ( the limit as x-> 1 of f'(x) ) involves l'Hopital's rule.